# Installing google cloud sdk while running docker compose (Need gcloud command for Airflow Tasks)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm using Airflow with docker compose and i'm looking for installing google-cloud-sdk for my tasks airflow.

I'm trying to add new service to install but i already have this error below : /bin/bash:  gcloud: command not found

This my docker_compose.yaml :

```
`version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.2}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor 
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
...............
...............
...............
gcloud-installer: 
    image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    volumes:
      - /Users/anis/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash"
`
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a command in Dockerfile to install it, build the image and use  this image in docker-compose